# Cauchy's Integral test for Convergence/Divergence

Tags: sequences-and-series

I don't understand how we are able to relate the convergence of a series seeing its Improper integral like

$\int_1 ^{\infty} f(n)dn < a_1 + a_2 +a_3+...... a_\infty$

If the integral diverges we can say that the series also diverges but if it converges how are we able to say that the series converges too. I am new to this. Any help is appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That's because we have$$\sum_{n=1}^\infty f(n)\geqslant\int_1^\infty f(x)\,\mathrm dx
\geqslant\sum_{n=2}^\infty f(n).$$It follows from the second inequality the the convergence of the integral implies the convergence of the series and from the first inequality that the convergence of the series implies the convergence of the integral.

Comment: how to get the second inequality?

Comment: Since $f$ is decreasing,$$\int_n^{n+1}f(x)\,\mathrm dx\geqslant\int_n^{n+1}f(n+1)\,\mathrm dx=f(n+1).$$So,$$\int_1^\infty f(x)\,\mathrm dx\geqslant\sum_{n=2}^\infty f(n).$$